# Remove options from Select Element with each additional DIV

Tags: javascript, forms, filter, html-select

I have a form and specifically a form button that with onclick adds new form elements, a label and a select element with different options. The form elements are set within a div. The below is a sample of the form. What I would like it to do is, with every selection and new select box, is to remove the selected item from the list, that way it's not a choice and can't be accidentally entered into the database twice as these options are many to many relationships. I've looked at different posts but haven't been able to find what I need.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JS Test</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="demo"></p>
        <p id="demo2"></p>
        <h1>Test Javascript</h1>

        <form id="form1">
            <fieldset id="java">
                <legend>Form Append Test</legend>
                <div id="tabelRow"></div>
                <div id="button">
                    <p><input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Click"></p>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var options = [
                {"value" : "1", "text": "FHA" },
                {"value" : "2", "text": "USDA" },
                {"value" : "3", "text": "VA" },
                {"value" : "4", "text": "Convnetional" },
                {"value" : "5", "text": "Construction" },
                {"value" : "6", "text": "Chattel" },
                {"value" : "7", "text": "Fannie MAE HARP" }
            ];

            var ol = options.length;
            var counter = 0;
            var fs = document.getElementById("java");
            var len = document.getElementById("demo");
            var button = document.getElementById("button");
            var getSelected = document.getElementsByClassName("selection").value;

            function myFunction() {
                var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
                var newLab = document.createElement("label");
                var labText = document.createTextNode("Product " + (counter + 1) + " ");
                var newSelect = document.createElement("select");

                newLab.appendChild(labText);
                newDiv.appendChild(newLab);
                newDiv.appendChild(newSelect);
                newDiv.className = "tablerow test";
                newSelect.className = "selection";

                if (counter == ol) {
                    alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter);
                }
                else {
                    for (var i = 0; i < ol; i++) {
                        var proMenu = options[i];
                        newSelect.options.add(new Option(proMenu.text, proMenu.value));
                    }

                    fs.appendChild(newDiv);
                    fs.insertBefore(newDiv, button);
                    counter += 1;
                    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = counter;
                    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = getSelected;
                }
            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I was thinking about using the array filter set to a condition of some kind, but I am unsure as to how to filter the same array in all of the previous 'div'. Am I on the right track with that?

Comment: So your procedure is to just delete the selected item, or delete and copy to a buffer to compare to the main list, or compare to what is in the DB?

Comment: So the form will be filled out and when it is submitted, will populate my database. I apologize if I wasn't very clear. so when a user fills out the form, each time they click on a new product supplied, the product that they already selected is removed from the new div and set of options (same options, just not with the product that was selected in the previous div).

Answer (score 1):

At the end of your script add a second function call that deletes the entry pointed to by 'counter -1'. If counter +=1 means point to the next item, move that code to the last work to be done, *after your db has been updated*. Your 'Alert' about a counter limit should also reset counter variables. *Remember that your creating a sequence of events*. The check for counter overflow can be done last if you always init the first function to '0'.
The sequence is:
1) On function call(); Init crucial variables first
2) Get selected item and store in variable. Save to db. Call next function.
3) Delete function: Deleted selected item from list (by index's1-7.etc) You can delete a field by copying it to a regex variable, then use regex to remove the characters in that field. That list ID number can be used as a key. Once deleted it is gone until you reset ther entire program.
4) Check for overflow
5) exit